# Color space conversion with cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I'm migrating from `cv` to `cv2` and I'm having difficulties finding an equivalent of the `cv.CvtColor` function.

I read in the documentation that `cv2.cvtColor` existed but I don't know how to use the third parameter.

`cv2.CV_BGR2Lab` doesn't exist. Neither does `cv2.CV2_BGR2Lab` and when I use `cv.CV_BGR2Lab` all I get is an error:

`cv2.cvtColor(img, img, cv.CV_BGR2Lab)`

`TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

A simple piece of code that produces the problem:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.cvtColor(img, img, cv.CV_BGR2Lab)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just have the parameters in the wrong order. The [cv2 docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cv2.cvtColor) show them in this order: `cv2.cvtColor(src, code[, dst[, dstCn]])`, which is different from what it was in [cv](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cv.CvtColor), where the order is: `cv.CvtColor(src, dst, code)`.

So, based on that, along with the information in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15339919/355230) regarding color conversion constants name changes, you'd need to use:

```
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB, img)
```

Comment: I didn't see that coming. I guess I should be more careful when reading the documentation. Anyway, for the moment I use `cv.CV_BGR2Lab`. Do you know if there is any cv2 version of it? I tried `cv2.CV_BGR2Lab` and `cv2.CV2_BGR2Lab` but with no luck.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) for `cv2.cvtColor()` seems to indicate it will do those kind of conversions. See the section that starts with `RGB <--> CIE L*a*b*` where it lists `CV_BGR2Lab`.

Comment: My explanation wasn't very clear. Let me start over. Currently I use `cv2.cvtColor(im, cv.CV_BGR2Lab, im)` and it does what I intend. But I find it a little messy to use a reference to `cv`, namely `CV_BGR2Lab` while using a function in `cv2`, `cvtColor`. So my question is: is there a cv2 version of `cv.CV_BGR2Lab`? I can't find any.

Comment: If there isn't an included `cv2.CV_BGR2Lab` you can easily make something of your own to avoid the messiness.

Comment: Apparently the color conversion constant's name was changed to `cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB`.

Answer (score 5):

Your looking for this constant

```
cv.CV_BGR2Lab --> cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB
```

And all the other constants for color conversion follow a similar pattern

```
cv.CV_<CONSTANT> --> cv2.COLOR_<CONSTANT>
```

I still have not found a good source (even the documentation) for determining how the constants are translated.

**Update:**
See discussions [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8861/what-opencv-constants-are-available) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328426/what-constants-codes-are-available-in-opencv) for more about constants.