# What constants (codes) are available in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

When calling Opencv function, usually a constant is provided to function call, like:

```
im_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

while I can't find reference to all available constants. Opencv distribution download (~250MB) doesn't contain `constants.h` file.

Google shows this pointer: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/interfaces/swig/filtered/constants.h?rev=277 which is deprecated as 8 years old.

In Opencv project at Github , there doesn't seem to be such file also, so does anyone have a link to a file that contains all available Opencv constants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e3ae36dcb3c1d523802f8642e5c3984db43637c4/modules/python/src2/defs) what you're looking for?

Comment: These seem to be only the ones in the cv interface.  Where are the ones in the cv2 interface? See discussion [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8861/what-opencv-constants-are-available).

Comment: `defs` reference file was removed around half year ago. Here is the latest available version from github history: [`defs`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/e3ae36dcb3c1d523802f8642e5c3984db43637c4/modules/python/src2/defs). I couldn't figure when exactly or why this file disappeared